# Gmail Promotions tab Annotations only show after reload or viewing e-mail

Tags: gmail, gmail-promo-tab

I am trying to implement code to get the annotations in the Promotions tab for a clients newsletter and i do get it to work.
However, it only shows the annotations **after** i reload the Promotions tab, or open and close the e-mail in question.
I tried with ld+json and with Microdata. Both get the same issue.

Is this a known issue? or am i doing something wrong?

Below is the code i tried:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    [{
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "logo": "https://www.website.com/images/logo.png"
      },{
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "DiscountOffer",
        "description": "15% off",
        "availabilityEnds": "2018-12-30T23:59:59-0100"
      },{
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "PromotionCard",
        "image": "https://www.website.com/images/promotionbanner.jpg"
      }]
</script>
```

And this is the microdata i tried

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="nameofthecompany"/>
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.website.nl/">
    <meta itemprop="logo" content="https://www.website.com/images/logo.png" />
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PromotionCard">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://www.website.com/images/promotionbanner.jpg"/>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/DiscountOffer">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="15% off"/>
    <meta itemprop="availabilityEnds" content="2018-12-30T23:59:59-0100"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the annotations in the promotion tab?Can you send a demo to my email(frankz4735@gmail.com) if you success on it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a stable environment what displays in the bundle only updates several times a day. To refresh what is in the bundle pull down on the promo tab screen to refresh. Or for more aggressive bundling and faster testing create a test account ending in promotabtesting@gmail.com. However, may still need to pull down to refresh (can repeat until your email populates in the bundle and can archive emails to make room for new emails in bundle).

Also, the expiration date format you have isn't correct - should have start and end date in the annotation. The end date needs to be in future, expired dates will cause the email not to populate in the bundle.

Source [website](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview).